# chrome asks me for a starting password whenever I start ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, password

whenever I start ubuntu and open google-chrome It asks me for my password. Is there any way to turn this request off or at least set a blank password to make it easier to use?

Comment: do you have a sync passphrase enabled? Settings > Sync (arrow) > 
Encrypt synced data with your own sync passphrase (bottom of page)

Comment: @Broadsworde there isn't Sync (arrow) in setting

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this:-

First, if you know the old password:

1. Go to `activities->passwords and keys`.
2. Right click on the `default keyring`
3. Choose `change password`
4. Type your old password
5. When it asks for a new password, just keep them blank and continue.

You will not get the box again.

Second, if you don't know the password:

1. Go to `home` folder press `ctrl+f`
2. Type `keyring` and delete all the files which are having `.keyring` as the extension and having the keyword `trashinfo.keyring` as the file name.
3. After doing all this, re-open Chrome.

It will ask for new password and re-validate the password(this will be the last time you will be filling the keyring password). And you will not get any keyring box again

Your problem will definitely get solved.

Comment: could you please tell me the exact addresses? for example where the activities is?

Comment: press `start` button from the keyboard and type `keys` in the search bar. You will get the `password and keys` icon

Comment: for further clarification: if you have your old password with you visit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzGYrHMWuPE. If you forgot or don't have password visit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wiNG-zMqFg

Comment: +1. I was told a long time ago you had to use a login password to prevent chrome from asking.